# How to logon by using sub authentication package on windows? Call of LsaLogonUser failed with nt_status 0xC00000A7 (STATUS_BAD_VALIDATION_CLASS)

Tags: c++, windows, authentication

I experimented on Windows 7 and also Windows Server 2008

First step:

I compiled the windows pass-through subauth example and released the subauth.dll, copy it to c:\windows\system32 and add the registry key Auth155 with string value "subauth" on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0

Second step:

I write the test program to execute login procedure by using the self-defined subauth, the main source code as the following:

```
size_t wcsByteLen( const wchar_t* str )
{
    return wcslen( str ) * sizeof(wchar_t);
}

void InitUnicodeString(UNICODE_STRING& str, const wchar_t* value,
 BYTE* buffer, size_t& offset )
{
    size_t size = wcsByteLen( value );
    str.Length = str.MaximumLength = (USHORT)size;
    str.Buffer = (PWSTR)(buffer + offset);
    memcpy( str.Buffer, value, size );
    offset += size;
}

LSA_STRING* create_lsa_string(const char* value)
{
    char* buf = new char[100];
    LSA_STRING* str = (LSA_STRING*)buf;
    str->Length = strlen(value);
    str->MaximumLength = str->Length;
    str->Buffer = buf + sizeof(LSA_STRING);
    memcpy(str->Buffer, value, str->Length);
    return str;
}

MSV1_0_SUBAUTH_LOGON * create_logon_info(int * size)
{
    BYTE * buf = new BYTE[2000]; 
    size_t offset = sizeof(MSV1_0_SUBAUTH_LOGON);
    MSV1_0_SUBAUTH_LOGON * p_logon_info = (MSV1_0_SUBAUTH_LOGON*)buf;

    WCHAR* domain = L"WIN7U-20140106B";
    WCHAR* user = L"test";
    WCHAR* workstation = L"WIN7U-20140106B";
    CHAR*  auth1 = "auth1";
    CHAR*  auth2 = "auth2";

    p_logon_info->MessageType = MSV1_0_LOGON_SUBMIT_TYPE::MsV1_0SubAuthLogon;
    InitUnicodeString(p_logon_info->LogonDomainName, domain, buf, offset);
    InitUnicodeString(p_logon_info->UserName, user, buf, offset);
    InitUnicodeString(p_logon_info->Workstation, workstation, buf, offset);
    InitString(p_logon_info->AuthenticationInfo1, auth1, buf, offset);
    InitString(p_logon_info->AuthenticationInfo2, auth2, buf, offset);
    memset(p_logon_info->ChallengeToClient, 0, MSV1_0_CHALLENGE_LENGTH);
    p_logon_info->ParameterControl = 0;
    p_logon_info->SubAuthPackageId = 155;

    *size = sizeof(MSV1_0_SUBAUTH_LOGON) + 
        wcsByteLen(domain) + wcsByteLen(user) + wcsByteLen(workstation) + 
        strlen(auth1) + strlen(auth2);

    return p_logon_info;
}


void logon_test_ex()
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    HANDLE handle;
    LSA_OPERATIONAL_MODE mode;
    int logon_info_size = 0;
    MSV1_0_SUBAUTH_LOGON * p_logon_info = create_logon_info(&logon_info_size);


    LSA_STRING* name = create_lsa_string("subauthtest");
    //status = LsaConnectUntrusted(&handle);
    status = LsaRegisterLogonProcess(name, &handle, &mode);
    if(status != STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        print_error("LsaRegisterLogonProcess", status);
    }
     
    LSA_STRING* package_name = create_lsa_string(MSV1_0_PACKAGE_NAME);
    
    ULONG package_id = 0;
    status = LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage(handle, package_name, &package_id);
    if(status != STATUS_SUCCESS)
    { 
        print_error("LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage", status);
    }
    printf("package id : %d\n", package_id);

    MSV1_0_SUBAUTH_REQUEST request ;
    request.MessageType = MsV1_0GenericPassthrough; //MsV1_0SubAuth;
    request.SubAuthPackageId = 155;
    request.SubAuthSubmitBuffer = new UCHAR[20];
    request.SubAuthInfoLength = 20;

    ULONG* ProtocolReturnBuffer = NULL;
    ULONG ReturnBufferLength = 0;
    NTSTATUS ProtocolStatus = 0;
    status = LsaCallAuthenticationPackage(handle, package_id, &request, sizeof(MSV1_0_SUBAUTH_REQUEST),
        (PVOID*)&ProtocolReturnBuffer, &ReturnBufferLength, &ProtocolStatus);
    if(status != STATUS_SUCCESS)
    { 
        print_error("LsaCallAuthenticationPackage", status);
    }
    
    printf("ProtocolStatus : %x\n", ProtocolStatus);


    LSA_STRING* origin_name = create_lsa_string("TTY1");
    
    TOKEN_SOURCE source = {0};
    strcpy_s(source.SourceName, "Test");
    bool test = AllocateLocallyUniqueId(&source.SourceIdentifier);

    void * ProfileBuffer = NULL;
    ULONG ProfileBufferLen = 0;
    LUID id = {0}; 
    HANDLE token = NULL;
    QUOTA_LIMITS limit = {0};
    NTSTATUS substatus = 0;

    status = LsaLogonUser(handle, origin_name, SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE::Batch, package_id, 
        p_logon_info, 1000, 
        NULL, &source, (PVOID*)&ProfileBuffer, &ProfileBufferLen, 
        &id, &token, &limit, &substatus);
     
    if(status != STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        print_error("LsaLogonUser", status);
    }

    printf("done\n");
}
```

Finally:

I run the test program by using PsExec as local system account, in order to grant the SeTcbPriviledge

```
D:\Software\PSTools>PsExec.exe -i -d -s "E:\Projects\subauthtest\x64\Debug\subauthtest.exe"
```

**The problem is that we always get the failed result by calling LsaLogonUser, the NT status value is 0xC00000A7(STATUS_BAD_VALIDATION_CLASS)**

What's the problem for my logon test program ?

Any ideas or suggestions ?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitwise left shift your subauth package id by 24 bits and then set the result to the ParameterControl variable of `MSV1_0_SUBAUTH_LOGON` structure, this configuration is undocumented.
You can use the `MSV1_0_SUBAUTHENTICATION_DLL_SHIFT` macro, as the following:

```
suauth_ptr->SubAuthPackageId = subauth_id;
suauth_ptr->ParameterControl = subauth_id<<MSV1_0_SUBAUTHENTICATION_DLL_SHIFT;
```